# Voice-recognition vs. speech-to-text tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there any difference between the [voice-recognition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-recognition) tag and the [speech-to-text](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-to-text) tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any meaningful difference in the questions.  I have merged the latter into the former, and added [speech-recognition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) as a synonym.